# Advantage of WebApplication Context in spring?

Tags: spring, struts

I need to integerate struts with spring.Basically  i want to get the bean from Spring containerin my action class.Like if i want to get any dao/helper class in my action class i should get it with Spring. I was going through a book which says the use of WebApplicationContext to get the bean in my action class.

My question is cant we use simple XMLBeanFactory or ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(with getBeanMethod) in my action class  instead of WebApplicationContext. (As WebApplicationContext has just one extra method i.e getServletContext() which we dont need  in the process of getting any model Bean).

My second question in the same application is if we further want to get any other bean in my businesshelper.java should i get it with WebApplicationContext or any other sublclass of ApplicationContext(like ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring in web application, `WebApplicationContext` is definitely a way to go. Not only it handles startup and shutdown for you, but it also nicely integrates with servlet environment. I.e. it automatically register itself in ServletContext under `org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT` key.

I am mentioning this because Struts probably uses this to locate web application context of your application. Otherwise how would Struts know this?

Regarding your second question: really go for `WebApplicationContext`. You can then (as a last resort) use `WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext()` to fetch beans.

`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is probably only useful when doing desktop development or in sandbox/tutorial projects.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz.As you said "I am mentioning this because Struts probably uses this to locate web application context of your application". Are you trying to say that struts action get to know the path of spring config file  from the key  provided by WebApplicationContext .Is that right?If not , what dou mean by web application context of your application?

Comment: You have two frameworks: Spring and Struts. You want Struts to somehow fetch beans from Spring so Struts needs a way to "connect" to Spring. This key is the simplest way because servlet context is available to both of them. And no, Struts do not read Spring context.xml files, but they do access Spring context object to getBean()s from.

Comment: If both the framework classes are in classpath and we do applicationcontext.getBean("MyClass1") in struts action class , will there be any issue in that? Why key is needed here.

Comment: The whole point of integrating Struts (both 1 and 2) with Spring is to let Struts fetch the beans from application context and inject them to your Struts actions automatically. If you are fetching beans manually using `getBean()` (or you use any Spring API in Struts classes), you are doing it wrong. The idea is to make Struts aware of (web) application context and get required beans transparently, without you even noticing.